# Error in Display the linked list

Tags: c

Folks,
    I don't know whether I am asking silly question. But tried to figure out my problem, but fail to that.

my structure is

```
typedef struct {
  uint16 nwkaddr;
  uint8 extaddr[8];
}device_t;

typedef struct node{
   device_t list;
   struct node *link;
}address_list;
```

The Data coming from UART is
1010,23CD1234,CD32454F,12F439AF,! . This I need to parse and store the mac list.

```
while(data[j] != '!')
        {
    if(data[i] == ',')
    {
      i = i+1;
      memset(addr, 0, 9);
      memcpy(addr, &data[i], 8);
                // addr[8] = '\0';
             if(addr != 0)
              {
                   insert_MacList(addr);
              }
    }
    i = i+8;
    j = i+1;
        }
```

the Created list is

```
void insert_MacList(uint8 *mac)
{
    address_list *curr, *temp;

    //curr = (address_list*)malloc(sizeof(address_list));
    curr = osal_mem_alloc(sizeof(address_list));
    strcpy((char*)curr->list.extaddr, (char const*)mac);
        temp = head;
        if(head == NULL)
        {
          head = curr;
          head->link = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
          while(temp->link !=NULL)
          {
            temp = temp->link;
          }
          curr->link = NULL;
          temp->link = curr;
        }
}
```

I am trying to print all address,But I am fail to get 23CD1234. But after that I am getting correctly.

```
void check_inlist(void)
{
  address_list *temp;

  temp = head;

  while(temp != NULL)
  {
      /*print data and send to UART*/  
      temp = temp->link;
  }
}
```

Why head is changing to second element, is 23 value creating some problem?. So can some help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `strcpy` to copy data that isn't null terminated!

You can change it like this:

```
strncpy((char*)curr->list.extaddr, (char const*)mac, sizeof curr->list.extaddr);  // strncpy won't write past the end of the array
```

Comment: `addr` what is passed to `insert_MacList()` is NUL terminated my `memset(...., 9 )`

Comment: The data doesn't fit. 8 characters + null terminator = 9 characters, which is larger than the buffer. If you want to keep the data null terminated you could extend the array to 9 chars.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
typedef struct {
  uint16 nwkaddr;
  uint8 extaddr[8];
}device_t;
```

But in `insert_MacList()` you call

```
strcpy((char*)curr->list.extaddr, (char const*)mac);
```

what copies 9 bytes (8 values + terminating `'\0'`). That might cause the problem.